# Why are swift functions so expensive?

Tags: ios, swift, function, sprite-kit

### Why are swift functions so expensive?

I have been writing an app using SpriteKit. Every frame, I recalculate the position of the CameraNode in the `update()` function. Lets call this the `//(cameraNodeCode)`. This current setup had little influence on the frames per second, it stayed at 60.

```
override func update() {
    //(cameraNodeCode)
}
```

As the cameraNodeCode is quite large, I thought it would be better to simplify my code and put it into a function: `updateCameraNode()`. Now this was what I had:

```
func updateCameraNode() {
    //(cameraNodeCode)
}

override func update() {
    updateCameraNode()
}
```

When I set up the code like this, the frames per second suddenly dropped to 20. I was very surprised as I didn't think functions were this expensive to call. I decided to test my theory with this code:

```
func emptyFunction() {

}

override func update() {
    emptyFunction()
    emptyFunction()
    emptyFunction()
    emptyFunction()
    emptyFunction()
}
```

As I predicted, when I did this the frames per second dropped drastically, to 4.1 frames per second!

**My questions are:**

- Why is this happening? Is it as I think and because simply calling a function is so expensive, or is there something I am missing?
- Is there a way that I could still keep my code looking simple without having 20 frames per second?

### Update

The key information that I left out was that I was using Xcode playgrounds. I think that this is a bug with SpriteKit and playgrounds. I have filed a bug report with Apple so I’ll see where that gets me.

Comment: Are you using Simulator or a real device?  I just tested this on iPhone 6 and everything runs @60 fps.

Comment: How are you doing this test? Swift has testing capability that it gives you for free (your project should contain a regular test swift file and a UI test swift file), and it has a `measure()` method as one of it's templates, perhaps you should use that to see where things are going wrong

Comment: @Whirlwind I'm actually doing this in the Xcode playgrounds, if that is any different.

Comment: @Zack do you get an answer from the Apple? If the problem was the playground lets close this question.

Comment: The fact the I was using playgrounds was not a “problem”. This was confirmed by Apple as a bug and I still believe it is a valid question.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking about Sprite-kit, I've tested your code to my iPhone 7 in a fresh "Hello world" template :

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    private var label : SKLabelNode?
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        // Get label node from scene and store it for use later
        self.label = self.childNode(withName: "//helloLabel") as? SKLabelNode
        if let label = self.label {
            label.alpha = 0.0
            label.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 2.0))
        }
    }
    func emptyFunction() {}
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
        //emptyFunction()
        //emptyFunction()
        //emptyFunction()
        //emptyFunction()
        //emptyFunction()
    }
}
```

If I don't commented the lines (remove // ) inside the update method, nothing change. I've always 60fps. Check your project to find what are the lines that caused  this drastic drop of fps, or if you test your code to a simulator try to a real device. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm actually testing this in Xcode playgrounds, sorry if I didn't make that more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Swift has three different methods of dispatch with different performance characteristics:

- *Direct Dispatch* should be very fast. Also known as *Static Dispatch*.
- *Table Dispatch* is a bit slower due to a method lookup in a witness table. Also known as *Dynamic Dispatch*.
- *Method Dispatch* is the most dynamic dispatch method. However, it is also the slowest one of the three.

You can force the compiler to use static dispatch by adding `final` to your method:

```
final func emptyFunction() {
}
```

This will also give the compiler additional opportunities for optimisation, such as inlining code. Remember to build with optimisations turned on, which is not the case for debug builds. Therefore you should make sure to choose the *release* configuration for performance testing. Debug builds of Swift projects are often notoriously slow.

See [this post on the Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27) for more information on method dispatch and the `static` keyword.

[This great post](https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2016/12/swift-method-dispatch/) explains the three kinds of method dispatch in Swift and when they are used.